# cómo reducir el tamaño de las flecha en laravel livewire?

Tags: laravel-livewire

el día de hoy vengo con otro problema, en mi código todo funciona bien, pero las flechas de paginación me aparecen enormes, qué podrá ser? ya limpie caché (safari, firefox, chrome)

lo renderizo asi:
esto es el componente:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Aporte;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class AporteComponent extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
```

y esto es en la vista:

```
<table>
@foreach($var as $v)
@endforeach
</table>
{{$var->links()}}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Que tal para los que les interese, esta es la respuesta. en el componente hay que colocarle esto:

```
protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
```

Pueden colocarlo después del use `WithPagination`.